# What is complexity of Control.Monad.Writer for w ~ [a]?

Tags: haskell, time-complexity

Assuming `tell = flip mappend` it should be quadratic, but that would make this `Writer` instance pretty useless. If it's really so, what can be done to improve performance?

I'm thinking of trick that was used in `Control.Monad.Free.Church` as well as `Control.Monad.Codensity`: it should be possible to reassociate `mappend` calls, just like `Codensity` reassociates `>>=`, but i haven't figured how exactly.

Comment: Use [difference lists](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/dlist).

Comment: Or better: [don't use](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.haskell.libraries/18980) `Writer` at all.

Comment: Getty wrote up a nice little piece about the issue with Writer not too long ago: http://blog.infinitenegativeutility.com/2016/7/writer-monads-and-space-leaks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sum this up:

1. Yes, `tell`ing an `[a]` has quadratic complexity in `Writer`. This can be avoided by using `DList` (which uses that `Codensity`-like trick I was talking about) or another datatype whose `mappend` isn't `O(n^2)`.
2. On top of that, `Writer` generates thunks for each `>>=` used to build up a computation. This is a problem because unlike the first case it can't be worked around. The solution is to use `State` monad instead.